# JTable autoscroll methods are one row too high

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

Here is an example table of what I have been using:

```java
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
contentPane.add(scrollPane);

table = new JTable();
DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"Row 1","Row 2"},0);
table.setModel(tableModel);
scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
```

I've attempted to use the following autoscrolling methods both with the same result.

```java
// Method 1
JScrollBar vertical = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
vertical.setValue(vertical.getMaximum());

// Method 2
table.scrollRectToVisible(table.getCellRect(table.getRowCount(), 0, true));
```

Both examples go to the near-bottom of the table, up until the last (bottom) row that the user has to scroll down to see, only to happen again when another row is added.

---

EDIT: Example code to replicate the problem

```java
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class ScrollTableEx extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public int i = 100;
    public JScrollPane scrollPane;
    public JPanel contentPane;
    public JTable table;
    public JButton add;
    public DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[] { "Int (+)", "Int (-)" }, 0);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScrollTableEx frame = new ScrollTableEx();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public ScrollTableEx() {
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setSize(500,400);
        
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane();

        table = new JTable();
        table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        table.setModel(model);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            model.addRow(new Object[] { i, i * -1 });
            Rectangle goodRect = table.getCellRect(model.getRowCount() - 1, 0, true);
            table.scrollRectToVisible(goodRect);
        }

        JButton add = new JButton("Add");
        add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Rectangle goodRect = table.getCellRect(model.getRowCount() - 1, 0, true);
                table.scrollRectToVisible(goodRect);
                model.addRow(new Object[] { i, i * -1 });
                i++;
            }
        });
        
        add(add, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

Comment: While not directly related to your problem, `scrollPane.setBounds(664, 0, 229, 236);` isn't doing you any favours.  You should relay on a suitable layout manager

Comment: It is how WindowBuilder for eclipse does it when you surround the component in a scrollpane; it hasn't caused trouble in any other project I've done it in.

Comment: `.setBounds` is a ticking time bomb and WindowsBuilder isn't doing that may favours either.

Comment: People use to use radioactive substances for all sorts of aliments too...doesn't mean it was the right thing to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, `JTable` and `TableModel` are both `0` indexed.  That is, the last value is actually `rowCount - 1`.

So when you use `table.getCellRect(table.getRowCount(), 0, true)`, it's actually returning a `Rectangle` of the right position, just with a `0` height, because the row doesn't actually exist.

Instead you want to use `table.getCellRect(table.getRowCount() - 1, 0, true)`

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class ScrollTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ScrollTable();
    }

    public ScrollTable() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"Test"}, 0);
                for (int index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
                    model.addRow(new Object[]{index});
                }

                final JTable table = new JTable(model);

                JButton add = new JButton("Add");
                add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        model.addRow(new Object[]{model.getRowCount()});
                        Rectangle badRect = table.getCellRect(model.getRowCount(), 0, true);
                        Rectangle goodRect = table.getCellRect(model.getRowCount() - 1, 0, true);

                        System.out.println("bad = " + badRect);
                        System.out.println("goodRect = " + goodRect);

                        table.scrollRectToVisible(goodRect);
                    }
                });

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.add(add, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I would avoid using `.setBounds` where possible.  It does not take into consideration the variety of differences that exist between different computers and OS's and while it might look perfectly fine when you are developing, when you move it another system, it could produce undeseriable results - IMHO

Comment: I tried what you suggested with adding -1 to the getrowcount() and it still doesn't work. How would I go about eliminating the setbounds on the scrollpane since my contentpane is absolutelayout, how would I get it exactly as I need it?

Comment: Odd, because it works for me just fine.  Can you run my test code?

Comment: I ran your code and it works just as I'd like mine to work scrolling all the way to the bottom.

Comment: Can you provide a full runnable example of your problem and update your answer...

Comment: So, I had a look at your example, basically, your getting the rectangle of the last row, you are updating the scroll position, you are THEN adding a new row...